# How do I list total of a field from database

Tags: mysql

I have 2 letter codes field "locale" in mysql db US,CA,MX,IT,DE
and for each locale i want to know how many users are in US,CA,MX,IT,DE

I have table users and field locale 
and where US is i wanna know the sum of how many users has locale set as US

I wanna note that I have a database of 250k users

thank you in advance

Comment: post table definitions.

Comment: In table users i have id, username, locale

Answer (score 0):

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE locale='US'

Comment: I want for each locale

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
   locale, COUNT(*) AS total
FROM
   table
GROUP BY locale
```